# SSRS 2008 - forward dependencies error references only one parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, bids

I'm putting together an SSRS report in BIDS 2008. I've got a parameter - we'll call it ParamA  - that's set to allow multiple values, and, in Available Values, I've set it to 'Get values from a query'. When I run the report, I get the following error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>
> The definition of the report '/Report2' is invalid.
>
> The report parameter 'ParamA' has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter "ParamA". Forward dependencies are not valid.

When other people get this error, it seems to involve multiple datasets, and the forward dependencies always deal with two different parameters. I'm using only one dataset, and only one parameter is cited in the error.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Can you post the query you use to populate ParamA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem. Using a multi-value parameters requires that each such parameter have its own dataset. I only had one dataset, and I was trying to point the MVP at it *and* run the report off of the same set. I don't know why that doesn't work, but I added a dataset for the MVP, and the error went away.

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked the order of your parameters in the report designer toolbar. If they are ordered incorrectly the report will fail because of the order required to make the dependencies work. You use the little blue up and down arrows to [set the order of report parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex7hp.jpg)

Comment: Why does the order of parameters matter? It seems like the order of the filters would be much more significant.

Comment: Sorry Ben, seems I misread the question must have been late... If you only have one parameter then my suggestion is no help. My suggestion applies if you have one parameter where one value is dependent on the value selected in the last parameter. In this case paraemters must be ordered correctly. In your case I think what is happening is that you have one dataset that uses a parameter and you are trying to use that same dataset to populate parameter values. This is leading to a self-reference of sorts. The dataset you are using to populate your param values cannot reference the parameter.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I figured out, after much blood, sweat, and tears. I didn't really understand why that fixed it, but I think you've explained it pretty well. Thanks.